# Retrieving JSON from API into C#

Tags: c#, json.net

I am brand new to C# after working with PHP and Javascript for years and struggling with the arrays / lists.

I realize C# is a strongly typed language, but am still learning what that means. I am surprised there is no equivalent to PHP's `print_r()`, or `var_dump()` which I have always used extensively in development to verify things got the right values at the right time.

I am hitting some endpoints that return JSON from a URL shortener that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "key": "WcoUC",
        "url": "https://www.shorty.com/WcoUC",
        "clicks": 17,
        "expires": "2017-12-22 15:30:00",
        "created_at": "2017-12-18 22:44:54",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-18 22:44:54",
        "redirect_to": "http://www.example2.com/"
    }
]
```

In my c# I have this method:

```
private static string start_get()
        {
            HttpWebRequest WebReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://www.shorty.com/api/v1/urls"));

            WebReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            WebReq.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi7w8VePMIh5i3pZ-S329KifQ9TbWHfsqMfV-HXmhej_9KcQRReIbytrILzyopoXY7p7kKN6ZnZTrFO9P9-1y3ohFJCBxZXvW_iwbA9hsVTj9ZtFbJGxaaIlUZa19knuDirQ";
            WebReq.PreAuthenticate = true;


            HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)WebReq.GetResponse();

            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.StatusCode);
            Console.WriteLine(WebResp.Server);

            string jsonString;
            using (Stream stream = WebResp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonString);
            return jsonString;
        }
```

With it's associated class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
    public string expires { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
    public string redirect_to { get; set; }
}
```

This is all working, but I am a little confused about why I have to setup a class to access each item in the JSON. My concern is that if the API gets updated with new items, they won't show up. So for example, let's say there was a new key:value added of `"referring_url":"http://www.stackoverflow.com"`.
When I dump the value of `item` I won't see that there. I am so used to javascript where it would just be `item.referring_url` and could have as many nested objects as it wanted to have without needing to define every little part.

Is it possible during this declaration

```
List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(jsonString);
```

to automatically assign everything it knows how to from the class I defined, but then assign the leftover to something that gets logged to the console or something so I know to handle it?

Is there a better method that will autocreate the classes in a more familiar way to someone transitioning from javascript?

Comment: Consider looking into `JsonSerializerSettings` with `MissingMemberHandling.Ignore`, and a version with `MissingMemberHandling.Error`.  With the latter, you can dump out any new objects found in the deserialization that are not yet covered in your existing class.  I use a release version to ignore, and a debug version to dump the new fields, but that's just my own implementation.

Comment: Assigning to a predefined class is a good, option if you can guarantee the structure. Otherwise you may want to dump your Json  into something more generalized that you can handle. Look into a c# Tuple https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: BTW, the issue you have is not really about c# being Strongly Typed (it's not, in the strict sense)https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2012/10/15/is-c-a-strongly-typed-or-a-weakly-typed-language/   It's about the structure of your JSON wich is really just a string as far as c# is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.Net has a way to receive errors from the process. Specify an `Error` delegate in the `JsonSeralizerSettings`. [Read about it here.](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationErrorHandling.htm)

Answer (score 1):

First go first: Use [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

When I usually request something to an API is because I need something and the API offers that to me... among a lot of other things I dont need. Hence, I only care about what I need, not about eveything it offers.

Anyway, if you need to know or log the raw content that is returned by the API, you simple get [System.Net.HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx).

PS: Thanks to attributes like [JsonProperty](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm), you can focus on what you need and how you need the entity to be

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to use Json.Net's [Linq-to-Json API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) instead of writing classes.  Then, all parts of the JSON will be available, similar to JavaScript.  For example:

```
string json = @"
    [
      {
        ""key"": ""WcoUC"",
        ""url"": ""https://www.shorty.com/WcoUC"",
        ""clicks"": 17,
        ""expires"": ""2017-12-22 15:30:00"",
        ""created_at"": ""2017-12-18 22:44:54"",
        ""updated_at"": ""2017-12-18 22:44:54"",
        ""redirect_to"": ""http://www.example2.com/""
      }
    ]";

JArray array = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (JObject obj in array.Children<JObject>())
{
    foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Properties())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value.ToString());    
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xyZvdO

Answer (score 0):

If you accept the losting intellisense, you can deserialize it a `dictionary` or `dynamic`;

```
string json = @"{'key' : 'k', 'url' : 'u', 'clicks' : 'c' }";
var keys = JObject.Parse(json).Properties();
//Dictionary
var keysDict = keys
    .ToDictionary(
        k => k.Name,
        v => v.Value.ToString());
//Dynamic
var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject.key);
```

Answer (score 0):

The application I am building is a Windows Form, so Console.Write that is part of so many tutorials / examples was not much help, but I configured a multiline textbox named `DebugBoxTest` and in the Form1.cs placed:

```
public void DebugBoxUpdate(string incomingString)
{
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(incomingString);
    DebugBoxTest.Text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Now I can dump formatted things into it using something like this from the `Main` area:

```
string results = start_get();
ThisForm.DebugBoxUpdate(results);
```

I know there are a lot of ways to skin a cat, and I am too new to properly upvote answers, but will accept whichever is at the top based off others feedback.

In the future I may augment this debug box into a button activated popout window with error handling for multiple data types, but this gets me started.

Comment: Just FYI, you only need 15 rep to upvote questions and answers.  You currently have 521 rep.  See [Help Center -> Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Also, you can dump the contents of the `JArray` as formatted JSON using `array.ToString()`.  It is a little shorter than using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array, Formatting.Indented)`.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I meant that from the 5 solutions, I don't know which is the "best" to vote on / accept. I know what worked for me, but it was kinda a combination effort. So to help the next user, I figured I would let more experienced .NET developers do the voting. I am using more of your solution than anyone else's at the moment though :)